# Descobrir localidade que o usuário acessa a minha página

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um domínio, www.dominio.com e www.dominio.com.br, o conteúdo é o mesmo ficando a diferença no arquivo de configuração com as mensagens que serão carregadas.

Qual a melhor técnica para descobrir a localidade que o usuário está acessando? para que eu possa definir via PHP qual arquivo de configuração carregar.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 

  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
   $(window).load(function(){
     $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
     $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
     $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
     $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
     }, "jsonp");
   });//]]> 

  </script>


 <body>

 <div id="ip"></div>
 <div id="address"></div>
 <hr/>Full response: <pre id="details"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use o Html5, JavaScript e Jquery para fazer o reconhecimento com geolocalização de quem acessar seu dominio. estes links deverão ajuda-lo: [Usando geolocalização com html5](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3653/usando-geolocalizacao-com-html5.aspx)

[API de Geolocalização (geolocation) do HTML5 com Javascript](https://tableless.com.br/esta-perdido-geolocalizacao/)